# How do you define boundedness in context of Lie groups?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I'm trying to tackle this problem of showing that the Lorentz group $$O(1,3)=\{M\in GL(4, \mathbb{R})\mid M\eta M^t=\eta\},$$ is non-compact. In order to do so I need to show that it is either not bounded or not closed.

For real numbers the idea of bounded sets make perfect sense. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set) "*A set $S$ of real numbers is called bounded from above if there exists some real number k (not necessarily in S) such that $k\geq s$ for all $s\in S $. The term bounded from below are similarly defined*".

What is now my question is, how this notion of upper and lower bounds apply to groups.
Is it as simple as saying that there exists a real number $k$, such that $k \geq m$ for all $m \in M$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The set you are interested in can be identified with a subset of $\mathbb R^4$. The idea would then be to show that the corresponding subset of $\mathbb R^4$ is not compact.

Comment: The notion of compactness is more general that "closed and bounded" because it holds for any topological space, not just metric spaces. However, smooth manifolds always admit a Riemannian metric, so they are metrizable and it is possible to talk about boundedness given a choice of metric. Also they can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some $N$ by the Whitney embedding theorem, so you can use the notion of boundedness from the ambient space.

Comment: Alex Ortiz: I can see how O(1,3) could be identified with a subset of R^16, since e.g. GL(4,R) consists of 4x4 matrices. But how do you see that it can be identified with a subset of R^4 ?

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if people posting questions would define the notation that they use. For example, I see no definition of what the symbol  means here. Nobody should have to guess what it means.

Comment: @DanAsimov given the context, the meaning is pretty standard. It is the standard Lorentzian “inner product” on $\Bbb{R}^4$ (and the overall sign $(-,+,+,+)$ vs $(+,-,-,-)$ is unimportant for the question here). And Alex’s comment above is probably just a typo.

Comment: @DanAsimov: Like peek-a-boo mentioned, yes, it was a typo. The point of my comment was to identify the given Lie group as a subset of some Euclidean space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: Each entry of the matrix must be bounded [see page 16. of Brian C Hall's book on Lie groups]. In particular, having bounded determinant is not enough (there is a counter-example on the same page).

**Long answer**:
Note that the result that **a subset is compact iff it is closed and bounded** is a special property of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, which is the content of the Heine-Borel theorem. It is not generally true for a topological vector space (TVS).

Now, matrix Lie groups are at the intersection of topology and groups, so when we ask whether a matrix Lie group has a certain property, we want to first think about whether we're looking at it as a group or as a TVS. Boundedness is a property of a TVS and its definition is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_(topological_vector_space)). The 'boundedness' you're thinking of is the special case of boundedness of intervals in $\mathbb R^1$, which is a TVS.

On page 16 of Brian C. Hall's book on Lie groups, he identifies (as in he considers these to be identical, in some sense) a matrix in $GL(n;\mathbb C)$ with the corresponding vector in $\mathbb R^{2n^2}$, where he has 'stacked' the real and imaginary parts of each entry of the matrix into a vector. Now we can just ask whether the set of matrices, interpreted as points in $\mathbb R^{2n^2}$, constitute a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^{2n^2}$. No longer do we need to talk about boundedness of groups, Lie groups, or matrices, just vectors in a Euclidean space. This is what I mean by 'viewing the Lie group as a TVS' - to ascertain whether a matrix Lie group is bounded, we need not concern ourselves with its qualities as a group.

Thereafter, we have that $A \subseteq \mathbb R^{2n^2}$ is bounded if $\exists c \in \mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in A$, $\| x\|_2 < c$. This follows from the definition of bounded sets linked above. Finally, we can use the equivalence of norms (i.e., vectors are *big/small* in one norm iff they are *big/small* in another norm) to replace this condition with: $\|x\|_{\infty}<\tilde c$, which is saying that the absolute value of each entry of the matrix is bounded from above by some constant.

Comment: Since most Lie groups are not vector spaces at all, and certainly not topological vector spaces, I find the wording of this answer to be confusing.

Comment: @DanAsimov Thanks, I have edited it to 'matrix Lie groups' instead of Lie groups. Does it look good to you now?